# Equilibrium states of a differential equation and their stability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

Considering the following equation;

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=x^2-x^4 $$

I want to

(1). Know which are its equilibrium states

(2). Say if such states are stable or unestable

---

*My aproach:*

(1). $x'=0 \implies x(t)=1, x(t)=0, x(t)=-1$

So this would be the equilibrium states, and how would i aproach (2)?, (3) *is there any method of drawing a phase portrait of it?*.

Comment: I would think a stable equilibrium is one where the derivative goes from positive to negative as $x$ moves to the right.  In this case it's $x^2(1 + x)(1 - x)$, which only switches sign at $x = 1$ and $x = -1$.  Since it's negative at $x \rightarrow -\infty$, it goes from negative, to positive, to positive, to negative.  This means that $x = 1$ is a stable equilibrium...at that point as you get close to $x = 1$, the derivative is positive--pushing you _towards_ the equilibrium point.  Once you go beyond $x = 1$ (to the right), the derivative is negative and pushes you _back_ to $x = 1$.

Comment: This page on [stability of equilibrium](http://mathinsight.org/stability_equilibria_differential_equation) may be helpful--it appears to confirm my above comment.